# Calculate stock value with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design, trigger, postgresql-performance

I'm working on inventory system web app. It is based on latest Ruby on Rails and PostgreSQL. I need to track products stock values base on purchases and sales quantities. You can check out my simplified [db schema](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6c1357ab300661f26d618bdbffebbaa3) (also shown below).

Table products has a *stock* field. This field must be calculated from products' total purchases and sales quantity.

`SUM(purchases.quantity) - SUM(sales.quantity)`

I'm looking for simple, performant and most important **race conditions safe** solution. My current (but not final) idea is to use db triggers here. But I have no mind how to implement them the right way.

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    name varchar,
    stock INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 CHECK (stock >= 0),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE purchases (
    id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    quantity INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    product_id INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_product FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products (id)
);

CREATE TABLE sales (
    id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    quantity INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    product_id INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_product FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products (id)
);

INSERT INTO products (name)
        VALUES('Super Power');

INSERT INTO purchases (product_id, quantity)
        VALUES(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 2);

INSERT INTO sales (product_id, quantity)
        VALUES(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 2);

SELECT
    *
FROM
    products
```

Comment: I'm having difficulty in understanding what exactly your question is. Could you show a `before` (table data) and `after` (either query result and/or table data) under your envisaged scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure if you have much of an issue, as long as you update the `products.stock` field every time you either `INSERT INTO` the `purchases` or `sales` tables. No need for a **Trigger** in this scenario. Also you should ensure your update on the `products.stock` happens in the same [**Transaction**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html) as your `INSERT INTO` the `purchases` and `sales` tables.

Alternatively you could also design your schema to not store the `stock` field on the `products` table. Rather create a **View** that joins `products`, `purchases`, and `sales` together, grouped on the `product` and aggregates the difference in `purchases` and `sales` per `product` as its `stock`, that way it's *instantly* always up to date whenever the `purchases` or `sales` change.

Comment: I tried using the `VIEW` approach which appears logical, but the problem with it is that there is no now way of ensuring that stock levels don't drop below 0 - see the end of [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4abe33c315a6928bf8181ddf35e0a0c2) - you can't put a `CHECK` constraint on a `VIEW`! It would be nice if you could!

Comment: @Vérace Yea that would be nice but certainly not a necessity. If OP needs to ensure the stock doesn't drop below 0 that would be very specifically dependent on his application's workflow and we'd need more context. (As depending on what his application is doing, it may already not even be a possibility.)

Comment: Unless there's something very wierd going on, having a product stock quantity below 0 is not normally desirable and would be a bug in any system I've ever worked with - apart perhaps from a "stock" of money in a bank where one can have an overdraft - but that's quite particular to a given industry - the word "product" implies (to me) some physical object - having said that, banks and other financial services companies do sell "products" that are abstract/intangible... hmm.... maybe you're correct, some OP input might be required?

Comment: @Vérace Yea, there's also a ton of other reasons depending on his application's workflow why it may just not even be possible to go below 0. That being said, I think it's good to account for minimal error checks, like you're thinking. I just personally like to keep my answers minimally sufficient and concise without any assumptions, as sometimes with some questions by some posters, it can turn into a tangent lol.

Comment: If I had a euro for every time I've answered a question, OP comes back with caveat_1 - fix caveat_1, then caveat_2 appears, fix that... and so on..., I'd be a wealthy man! :-)

Comment: @Vérace I measure your wealth in **reputation score**, in which case you're far more wealthy than me. 

Comment: Guys, thanks for answers. @J.D. you mentioned transactions here. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=08eb3354246102c043358c83ca333a66 Like so? And yes, I would need a constraint on stock below 0. So, if I'll set a check constraint on stock, I would not need app logic there for rollback if stock < 0?

Comment: @Molfar Yes I think your **transaction** syntax is correct in that linked example. If you do want to set a constraint on `stock`, it would still be good to have application logic to check as well (redundancy for error prevention is a good thing), but yes you *should* be covered by just the database constraint as well. In that case, either Verace's or my first answer should be sufficient for you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer this, I did the following (see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=581655768077bfefc6aa5f9a83c928e1)):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product;
CREATE TABLE product 
(
  product_id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  name varchar,
  stock INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (product_id),
  CONSTRAINT product_stock_gt_0_ck CHECK (stock >= 0) -- can't have negative stock levels
);
```

I tend to use the singular for table names - a table is a set of things - just my preference - it also makes things easier to remember.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS purchase;
CREATE TABLE purchase 
(
  purchase_id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  product_id INT NOT NULL,
  quantity INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT purchase_product_fk FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product (product_id),
  CONSTRAINT purchase_gt_0-ck CHECK (quantity > 0) -- can't have a 0 or negative purchase
);
```

I changed the name of the `FK` to table_field_fk - more descriptive IMHO. Also, I added the `CHECK` constraint so that the purchase quantity would always be greater than or equal to 1 - one doesn't purchase 0 items and a negative quantity for a purchase makes no sense.

You could just have one table, say `txn` (short for transaction, which is an SQL keyword (see below) so I didn't use that. I  **could** have used keywords by enclosing them in double quotes - but this is non-portable and messy (makes for difficulty in reading the SQL and produces potentially confusing error messages).

and

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sale;
CREATE TABLE 
sale 
(
  sale_id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  product_id INT NOT NULL,
  quantity INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT sale_product_fk FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product (product_id)
);
```

I inverted the order of `product_id` and `quantity` in your schema - more logical from my POV. Note also that I put the `_fk` at the end - this means that related objects sort together when using `\d` to describe database objects.

I didn't do the `INSERT`s that were in your schema - instead I did the following:

```
INSERT INTO product (name, stock) 
VALUES 
('product1', 100), ('product2', 200), ('product3', 300);
```

You now have a choice - update using "pure" DML or via `TRIGGER`s.

To perform `UPDATE`s in a `"race-safe"` way using a query, I did the following:

```
START TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE READ WRITE;  -- READ COMMITTED (default)
INSERT INTO purchase (quantity, product_id) VALUES (1000, 1); -- also suitable
INSERT INTO purchase (quantity, product_id) VALUES (2000, 2);
INSERT INTO purchase (quantity, product_id) VALUES (3000, 3);
UPDATE product SET stock = stock + 1000 WHERE product_id = 1;
UPDATE product SET stock = stock + 2000 WHERE product_id = 2;
UPDATE product SET stock = stock + 3000 WHERE product_id = 3;
COMMIT;
```

Note that I used the `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation level - this isn't strictly necessary - the `READ COMMITTED` level should be more than adequate as you are not reading and rereading values from other tables which may change between your first and second read. I would urge you to check out `[PostgreSQL's documentation][1]` and the internet generally ([`here`](https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-work-postgresql-transactions) for example) on the issue of transaction isolation. It's a tricky topic and not having a good grasp of it can lead to subtle, tricky-to-find bugs.

After this transaction, I now have:

```
SELECT * FROM product;
```

Result:

```
product_id      name    stock
         1  product1    1100
         2  product2    2200
         3  product3    3300
```

We can see (taking `product_1`) that we have our original 100 plus the 1000 of the purchase.

and

```
SELECT * FROM purchase
```

Result:

```
purchase_id product_id  quantity
          1          1      1000
          2          2      2000
          3          3      3000
```

So, this is relatively simple. However, the only fly in the ointment here is that you have to remember to update **two** tables instead of one and you'll have to remember this at every point in the user interface in your application where the user makes a new purchase. I also included an example of the same thing using the `sale` table (not shown - see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=581655768077bfefc6aa5f9a83c928e1)).

The way of obviating this brain overhead memory requirement<sup>(*)</sup> so that when you make a `purchase`, the `product` table `stock` field is also updated is to use `TRIGGER`s as follows:

<sub>(*) an [interesting book](http://if%20composite%20primary%20keys%20are%20bad%20practice%20and%20if%20not,%20in%20which%20scenarios%20is%20their%20use%20beneficial?) on this topic!</sub>

First, PostgreSQL requires a procedure/function to be called by a `TRIGGER` as follows (you might [this](https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/everything-you-need-know-about-postgresql-triggers) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343984/insert-trigger-to-update-another-table-using-postgresql) helpful):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION purchase_after_ins()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  UPDATE product
  SET stock = stock + new.quantity
  WHERE product_id = new.product_id;
  
  RETURN NEW;
  
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

and then the calling `TRIGGER` itself:

```
CREATE TRIGGER purchase_after_ins_tr
  AFTER INSERT
  ON purchase
  FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE purchase_after_ins();
```

Run some SQL using an `INSERT` into the `purchase` table:

```
START TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED READ WRITE;  -- could have SERIALIZABLE
INSERT INTO purchase (quantity, product_id) VALUES (1111111, 1);
COMMIT;
```

and then we check our result:

```
SELECT * FROM product
ORDER BY product;
```

Result:

```
product_id  name    stock
1   product1    1112100
2   product2    1978
3   product3    2967
```

So, we see that our `INSERT` into the `purchase` table has resulted in the same number of items being added to the appropriate stock level of `product_1`.

I also tried making a "purchase" of -111111110 of `product_1` - equivalent to a sale (not shown, see the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=581655768077bfefc6aa5f9a83c928e1)) and the database threw an appropriate error:

```
ERROR:  new row for relation "purchase" violates check constraint "purchase_qty_gt_0_ck"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (5, 1, -111111110).
```

This demonstrates that the `TRIGGER` doesn't override or ignore your table DDL, i.e. `CHECK` constraints - this also holds for `FK`s also (or anything else).

`TRIGGER`s are an **extremely** powerful mechanism for turning your database into a fully-fledged application in its own right (minus the GUI) and I cannot emphasise enough how important it is to master them.

I have only included the bare bones of a solution - I leave it up to you to construct appropriate `TRIGGER`s for an `INSERT` on the `sale` table and potential `UPDATE`s to the `purchase` table *inter alia*. **Exactly** how all these will work will depend on your own business rules and practices in your own industry.